# Upgrading symfony to 3.0 - bad distribution-bundle version

Tags: php, composer-php, symfony

I'm trying to upgrade from symfony 2.7 to 3.0. I made my code deprecation-free and updated `composer.json` with new packages versions according to this [one](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/v3.0.0/composer.json). When I start upgrade with command: `composer update --with-dependencies symfony/symfony` it gives me error as follow:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested package sensio/distribution-bundle == 4.0.4.0 could not be found.
  Problem 2
    - The requested package sensio/generator-bundle == 2.5.3.0 could not be found.

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion> for more details.

Read <https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.
```

I have no idea from where are coming these strange versions of that two packages. My `composer.json` looks like:

```
{
    "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { "": "src/", "SymfonyStandard": "app/" }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "symfony/symfony": "3.0.*",
        "twig/extensions": "~1.0",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.8",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~5.0",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0.2",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "~3.0"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "SymfonyStandard\\Composer::hookRootPackageInstall"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::removeSymfonyStandardFiles"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::removeSymfonyStandardFiles"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "incenteev-parameters": {
            "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
        },
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "3.0-dev"
        },
        "symfony-assets-install": "symlink"
    }
}
```

I can't see where I made a mistake, any suggestions?

**Edit:**

Executing just `composer update` instead of `composer update --with-dependencies symfony/symfony` seems to solve problem, all packages updates successfully, by after that, it shows:

```
[RuntimeException]
An error occurred when executing the "'cache:clear --no-warmup'" command:
Fatal error: Class 'Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput' not found in /home/wombat/htdocs/gugupanel/app/console on line 17
```

Comment: Use ^ instead of ~ for the sensio libraries.  Too lazy to look up the difference but they install cleanly for me and it's what the S3 composer.json uses.  Be ready to have lots and lots of form issues.  Might be better to go to 2.8 first.

Comment: @Cerad - changing ~ to ^ does not make any difference, same error.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a composer.json that almost matches yours which works for me.

```
{
    "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": { "": "src/" },
        "files": [ "app/AppKernel.php" ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": { "Tests\\": "tests/" }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "symfony/symfony": "3.0.*",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.5",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^1.6",
        "doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle": "^1.2",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^2.3",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^2.8",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "^5.0",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "^2.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^4.8",
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "^3.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^2.7"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-bin-dir": "bin",
        "symfony-var-dir": "var",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "symfony-tests-dir": "tests",
        "symfony-assets-install": "relative",
        "incenteev-parameters": {
            "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
        },
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "3.0-dev"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to fix those kind of problems with composer, I recommend you to remove the library from the composer.json and then use the composer require.

1. Remove the `"sensio/distribution-bundle": "~5.0"` dependency
2. Run composer update
3. Still error? Repeat 1 and 2 with the other libraries causing errors.
4. No error? Now you composer require the libraries that you removed:

   composer require sensio/distribution-bundle

This way composer will find the best suits for you. Its also good to keep a more stable composer json!

Don't forget to commit your `composer.lock` file after all the updates go fine, this way the other developers will use the same versions as you are.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Removing `distribution-bundle` dependency caused even more errors, with almost all installed libraries. Removed whole vendor directory, `composer.lock` file to install everything again and still just one big bag of errors. That composer thing is crap...

Comment: What was the error when you removed distribution-bundle?

Comment: It was a very long list of `- don't install symfony/process v2.6.8|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0` with different versions of `symfony/process` and `- sensio/distribution-bundle v4.0.4 requires symfony/process ~2.2 ->` with another long list of different versions.

Comment: Yep.  Composer is crap unless you use it properly.  If only you had an example of a working file.

Comment: This is the only solution that works as far as I know. I have tried keeping up with right package versions manually, but that was a nightmare I woke from.